# Keepass and Chrome Mobile?

Tags: chrome-for-android

is there a way to use something like ChromeIPass on Android for the Chrome Mobile Browser?
I installed the KeepassDroid App but I couldn't figure out a way to integrate it.

Greetings, Steven

Answer (score 2):

Lastpass works, but is quite annoying to use.  (It's still better than nothing, though).

In case you didn't know, Chrome for Android will sync with Chrome for desktop.

Comment: Yes, Chrome sync would work for passwords unless one doesn't need cross-browser sync.

Comment: LastPass input method is great which works with all apps on Earth, but it's not free...

Comment: I forgot that it wasn't free, and I'd dispute that it works "great"; I find it annoying and frustrating every time I use it.